# Entity Framework - No connection string could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I realize this question has been asked and answered before but the answers I've found don't quite apply to my problem. I have **one project only** which is a WPF (MVVM) app using Entity Framework. The project is set up as follows:

[image: Project Overview]

Namespaces are set according to folder structure: EF_Test, EF_Test.Model and EF_Test.ViewModel. The App displays data from the DB in a DataGrid. It compiles and runs fine when I start the app, even on a different machine.

However, Visual Studio complains about the DataContext in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="EF_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EF_Test"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:vm1="clr-namespace:EF_Test.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm1:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
...
```

On `<vm1:MainWindowViewModel/>` it says *No connection string ... could be found in the application config file*. App.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BusinessEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.EntityModel.csdl|res://*/Model.EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.EntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ursqldb-01;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

As I said, the project compiles and runs (for me). My teammate however experiences a crash on startup. He has the exact same rights on the DB like me and Entity Framework is set up to use windows authentication for connecting to the DB. When he launches the app it crashes at `DataEntities.C_PKE_Test.Load();` within the ViewModel constructor. I'm loading the data in the ViewModel constructor as follows:

```
DataEntities = new BusinessEntities();
DataEntities.C_PKE_Test.Load(); // <- Crashes here only when my teammate runs the app
Collection.Source = DataEntities.C_PKE_Test.Local;
DataEntities.C_PKE_Test.Local.CollectionChanged += Local_CollectionChanged;
Collection.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("pke_id", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

The exception in my teammate's windows event viewer looks like this:

> Description: The process terminated due to an unhandled exception. exception 
>   information: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,
>   Boolean, System.Action'1)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,
>   Boolean, System.Action'1)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject,
>   Boolean, Boolean)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.BulkCopySimpleResultSet,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject, Boolean ByRef)
>   ...

I suspect the complaint in the XAML editor and the crash on my teammate's user are connected. When I set the DataContext in code behind, the app doesn't crash but the DataGrid doesn't display any data when my teammate runs the app. Logging messages reveal that in this scenario the statement `DataEntities.C_PKE_Test.Load();` throws an exception: *An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.* And an inner exception: *Invalid object name 'dbo._PKE_Test*

Yet the table exists and we can both query it in SQL Management Studio. Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: You should catch the exception in your application, log it and then determine why it happens and fix the issue."The process terminated due to an unhandled exception" says nothing about the actual cause of the exception. Catch it and check the InnerException.Message property.

Comment: You mean not doing work in the ViewModel or in the MainWindow constructor? I'm not doing any work in my MainWindow constructor. Question has been updated with the exception messages.

Comment: dbo._PKE_Test is a table in our business database. The table was set up in SQL Server Management Studio. My teammate and I can both query the table in the SQL Server Management Studio but only I can display the data from the table within my app. It seems the app is trying to query the wrong DB ('master' maybe) when my teammate is running the app. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the name of the database as `Initial Catalog` in the connection string:

```
<add name="BusinessEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.EntityModel.csdl|res://*/Model.EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.EntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=ursqldb-01;Initial Catalog=YOURDATABASENAME;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: While Juan's answer also fixes the problem, this has the advantage that the DB to use from the app is specified in one central place, no matter what the default schema of the individual user is.

Answer (score 1):

This may have to do with the schema your teammate is assigned to.

Go to the `Security` node of the database in question in SQL server Management Studio, expand it, right click on your teammate's account and hit `Properties`.

On the `General` Page, you should be able to set the default schema for his account. Make sure it matches yours.

Comment: This was it. I thought the DB name to connect to would be recorded somewhere within the Entity Framework.